# Why does my onClick="window.location.hash = '#top'" not work if the user has to scroll to get to the link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, scroll, jscrollpane

I have links within a content container div (which is inside another container div) like so

```
<a id="top"></a>
<p class="studioLine">

    <span style="font-weight:bold;" class="allCaps">
    <a onClick="window.location.hash = '#consent'">age consents</a><br/><br/>
    <a onClick="window.location.hash = '#healthandsafety'">health and safety</a><br/><br/>
    <a onClick="window.location.hash = '#custom'">custom tattoo</a><br/><br/>
    <a onClick="window.location.hash = '#pierceprocedure'">piercing procedure</a><br/><br/>
    <a onClick="window.location.hash = '#pricing'">pricing</a>
    </span><br/><br/>
</p>
```

Then at the end of each of these sections there is a back to top link like so

```
<a onClick="window.location.hash = '#top'">back to top</a>
```

All the links from the top of the page work fine. But the "back to top" link only works if the user doesn't have to do any scrolling to read text before clicking the link. If they do, then the page loads to the top of the outside container instead of the inner one.

However, if I then manually scroll back up to the top of the page and click one of those navigation links at the top (i.e. pricing) again, then it will still work and so will the "back to top" link (as long as I don't have to scroll to reach it).

I'm also using a script for the scrollbars (jScrollPane - v2.0.19) which I feel may have something to do with the problem?

Although I have also tried changing the name for "top" to something else and still have the same issue.

****EDIT******
I've since found out that it is definitely the jScrollPane that is affecting it, and have found this solution:

```
hijackInternalLinks: true;
```

BUT, while adding this in makes my links work, it changes all of the style formatting I've done for the scroll bars and also adds in unnecessary scroll bars (on pages that don't require scrolling).

Comment: use #wrapper, or what ever your outer div is

Comment: `window.location.hash='#top'` append #top to the end of the url

Comment: I've taken all of the #'s out of the .hash links but it doesn't make a difference - behaves exactly the same. 

Using the outer div is essentially how it's already behaving, which isn't what I want it to do. I want it to scroll to the top of the text of the inner container, not to the top of the outer container.

The only time it doesn't work how I want it to is after scrolling down...

Comment: If I take out the use of the scroll-pane then everything works fine, so it's definitely something to do with the use of jScrollPane :/